# how do I exclude blank or null in a report

Tags: civireport, reports

I'm currently trying to set up a simple report for bookkeeping transactions for the last month. It's was great except for the fact it is also including paypal fees on top of the full transaction amount (this makes it look very much like we collected the full transaction amount (including the paypal fee), plus we collected the paypal fee as well.) I though it would be simple enough to filter these out, they are easily identifiable by the fact that they don't have a payment method or a financial type at all. I don't seem to be able to filter out null/blank values though: I have to select a value from the list, null/blank is not an option.

I have found I can exclude them based on account codes and this solves my immediate problem. I would, however, like to know if there is a way to exclude items with blank or null values. I could see it being very handy in the future.

It would also be nice to have the pay pal fees subtract their values in a report rather than add them? Possible at all?

Using civiCRM version 4.7.3 right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround -

Select operator as `is not one of` and multi-select all the values in the dropdown. Result shown will be the record not having the selected values.

For Eg - Financial Type -> is not one of -> all the values in the dropdown -> Preview Report

Can that work for you?

Comment: That will work most of the time.