# Excluding blank or null values from report

Tags: search, reports

I'd like to create a report that includes a record if ANY value for a particular column is present, but excludes if there is no value.

For example, for gender of Male or Female, I'd like to filter if someone entered either value. Entries without a value would be excluded.

I did find [this question/answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10224/how-do-i-exclude-blank-or-null-in-a-report) which suggests using multiple choice selection as a workaround.

This answer is not sufficient, since the columns that I want to choose do not have the option to multi select values.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Search Builder (**Search menu » Search Builder**) to select your field with an operator of "Not Empty" (see screenshot below).  It's not clear when you say "Report" if a search is sufficient - if it is, you're done.

If you DO need a report, add these users to a group (possibly a smart group, depending on whether you need this on an ongoing basis).  Then generate your report, filtering by members of the group.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you. I figured that it would be easiest for me to just build a search instead of going through reports. Good to know about the step of making a group and then filtering from there.